# Cloning a Game - Dev diary while using original assets

Tags: legal

I'm currently cloning a game and still using the sound and graphic assets of the original.

I know that I may not distribute those assets but what about publishing a video of my progress as part of a dev diary, is that allowed?

Thanks.

Comment: Keep in mind that 99% of the answers here are not from actual lawyers. Furthermore - the answer may depend on your territory. Take it with a grain of salt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you obtain written consent from the owner, **probably not**. This is one way of distributing the assets, after all. Maybe that's some kind of fair use but I wouldn't bet on it, so your best option is just to ask for permission.

Comment: I don't think it's fair use, since a devlog is essentially marketing.